# C - Sorting strings in a file, but with limited memory usage

Tags: c, file, sorting

I am writing a program, which generates arrays of characters and adds them to a file, so it's like an array of arrays of characters.  Generating part is fine, also file is created and saved properly.
However, one of the tasks says that I am  supposed to sort records in a  file, using insertion sort (also using librabry and system options). The key of sorting is the value of the first byte of a record. Also, I can only have two records in the memory at once.

So far, I've got this code: to generate `recordsAmount` of records of size `bufferSize`.

```
void generate(char *path, int recordsAmount, int bufferSize)
{

    int i,j;

    int start = open(path,O_CREAT| O_TRUNC | O_WRONLY | S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);
    for(i = 0; i < recordsAmount; i++){
             char buffer[bufferSize];
        for(j = 0; j < bufferSize; j++){
            buffer[j] = 'A' + (rand() % 26);
            write(start, &buffer[j], sizeof(buffer[j]));

        }

    write(start, "\n", 1);
    }

}
```

Then I have the code of a sorting function usisng system options:

```
void sysSort(char *path, int recordsAmount, int bufferSize)
{
    int file = open(path,O_RDWR);
    if((file = open(path, O_RDWR)) == NULL){
        printf("Error while opening  a file");
    }
    int i, j;
    for(i = 1; i < recordsAmount; i++)
    {
       unsigned char bufferOne[bufferSize+1];
       unsigned  char bufferTwo[bufferSize+1];
        lseek(file, sizeof(bufferOne)*i, SEEK_SET);
        read(file, &bufferOne, sizeof(bufferOne));

         j = i - 1;


        lseek(file, sizeof(bufferTwo)*j, SEEK_SET);
        read(file, &bufferTwo, sizeof(bufferTwo));
        while((unsigned char) bufferTwo[0] > (unsigned char) bufferOne[0]){

        lseek(file, sizeof(bufferTwo)* (j+1), SEEK_SET);
        write(file, &bufferTwo, sizeof(bufferTwo));
        j--;
        lseek(file, sizeof(bufferTwo) * j, SEEK_SET);
        read(file, &bufferTwo, sizeof(bufferTwo));
        }
        lseek(file, sizeof(bufferOne) * (j+1), SEEK_SET);
        write(file, &bufferOne, sizeof(bufferOne));

    }
}
```

And very similar for librabry functions sort:

```
void libSort(char *path, int recordsAmount, int bufferSize)
{
    FILE *file = fopen(path, "r+");
    int i, j;
    for(i = 1; i < recordsAmount; i++)
    {
        char bufferOne[bufferSize+1];
         char bufferTwo[bufferSize+1];
        fseek(file, i* sizeof(bufferOne),SEEK_SET);
        fread(bufferOne, sizeof(char),(size_t) bufferSize ,file);
         j = i-1;

          fseek(file, sizeof(bufferTwo), SEEK_SET);
          fread(bufferTwo, sizeof(unsigned char), (size_t) bufferSize, file);
         while((unsigned char) bufferTwo[0] > (unsigned char) bufferOne[0]){
             fseek(file, sizeof(bufferTwo)* (j+1), SEEK_SET);
             fwrite(&bufferTwo, sizeof(unsigned char), (size_t) bufferSize, file);
            j--;
            fseek(file, sizeof(bufferTwo) * i, SEEK_SET);
            fread(&bufferTwo, sizeof(unsigned char), (size_t) bufferSize, file);

         }
        fseek(file, sizeof(bufferOne) * (j+1), SEEK_SET );
        fwrite(&bufferOne, sizeof(unsigned char), (size_t) bufferSize, file);
    }
}
```

However, when I use `sysSort` - nothing happens, the file stays the same. When I try to use `libSort`, I get segmentation fault. I'm not really sure what causes that, Any ideas? Any help would be appreciated
Edit, as suggested by LSerni I used valgrind for sorting. I tried to sort file ZZZ which has 10 rows of 10 characters using system and library functions.
For system:

```
==803== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==803== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==803== Using Valgrind-3.15.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==803== Command: ./program2 sort ZZZ 10 10 sys
==803==
==803== Warning: invalid file descriptor -1 in syscall read()
==803== Warning: invalid file descriptor -1 in syscall read()
==803== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==803==    at 0x109DB6: sysSort (in /mnt/c/Users/Czaro/ubuntu/program2)
==803==    by 0x1095A7: main (in /mnt/c/Users/Czaro/ubuntu/program2)
==803==
==803== Warning: invalid file descriptor -1 in syscall write()
==803== Warning: invalid file descriptor -1 in syscall read()
==803== Warning: invalid file descriptor -1 in syscall read()
==803== Warning: invalid file descriptor -1 in syscall write()
==803== Warning: invalid file descriptor -1 in syscall read()
==803== Warning: invalid file descriptor -1 in syscall read()
==803== Warning: invalid file descriptor -1 in syscall write()
==803== Warning: invalid file descriptor -1 in syscall read()
==803== Warning: invalid file descriptor -1 in syscall read()
==803== Warning: invalid file descriptor -1 in syscall write()
==803== Warning: invalid file descriptor -1 in syscall read()
==803== Warning: invalid file descriptor -1 in syscall read()
==803== Warning: invalid file descriptor -1 in syscall write()
==803== Warning: invalid file descriptor -1 in syscall read()
==803== Warning: invalid file descriptor -1 in syscall read()
==803== Warning: invalid file descriptor -1 in syscall write()
==803== Warning: invalid file descriptor -1 in syscall read()
==803== Warning: invalid file descriptor -1 in syscall read()
==803== Warning: invalid file descriptor -1 in syscall write()
==803== Warning: invalid file descriptor -1 in syscall read()
==803== Warning: invalid file descriptor -1 in syscall read()
==803== Warning: invalid file descriptor -1 in syscall write()
==803== Warning: invalid file descriptor -1 in syscall read()
==803== Warning: invalid file descriptor -1 in syscall read()
==803== Warning: invalid file descriptor -1 in syscall write()
==803==
==803== HEAP SUMMARY:
==803==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==803==   total heap usage: 0 allocs, 0 frees, 0 bytes allocated
==803==
==803== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==803==
==803== Use --track-origins=yes to see where uninitialised values come from
==803== For lists of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -s
==803== ERROR SUMMARY: 9 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

For library:

```
==804== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==804== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==804== Using Valgrind-3.15.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==804== Command: ./program2 sort ZZZ 10 10 lib
==804==
==804== Invalid read of size 4
==804==    at 0x48E24A7: fseek (fseek.c:35)
==804==    by 0x10A014: libSort (in /mnt/c/Users/Czaro/ubuntu/program2)
==804==    by 0x1095F6: main (in /mnt/c/Users/Czaro/ubuntu/program2)
==804==  Address 0x0 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==804==
==804==
==804== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==804==  Access not within mapped region at address 0x0
==804==    at 0x48E24A7: fseek (fseek.c:35)
==804==    by 0x10A014: libSort (in /mnt/c/Users/Czaro/ubuntu/program2)
==804==    by 0x1095F6: main (in /mnt/c/Users/Czaro/ubuntu/program2)
==804==  If you believe this happened as a result of a stack
==804==  overflow in your program's main thread (unlikely but
==804==  possible), you can try to increase the size of the
==804==  main thread stack using the --main-stacksize= flag.
==804==  The main thread stack size used in this run was 8388608.
==804==
==804== HEAP SUMMARY:
==804==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==804==   total heap usage: 1 allocs, 1 frees, 472 bytes allocated
==804==
==804== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==804==
==804== For lists of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -s
==804== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
Segmentation fault
```

Comment: You can run the file through valgrind to check where it does things it shouldn't.

Comment: I did, pasted what I got in the post, never used valgrind before...

Comment: `if((file = open(path, O_RDWR)) == NULL){` You are confusing file pointers and file descriptors here. `open()` returns an int, not a pointer.

Comment: Also, `sysSort()` opens the file twice (or at least attempts to do so), and closes it zero times.  That will leak up to two open file descriptions per call.

Comment: On the other hand, `libSort()` does not check whether opening the file succeeded.  The `sysSort()` results suggest that opening *will not* succeed, and that would explain why you're getting a segfault in `libSort()` (variable `file` is `NULL`, I think you'll find).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in both `sysSort()` and `libSort()` appears to be that they are not successfully opening the file.  `open()` returns -1 in this event (not `NULL`), which matches with all the warnings you're getting in that case.  Since `sysSort()` fails to open the file, it seems likely that `libSort()` also fails to open it, but that function does not test whether opening succeeded.  In the event that instead it fails, `libSort()`'s uses of the resulting null pointer produce undefined behavior, with a segfault being an altogether plausible manifestation.

My guess as to the underlying reason would be that the file's permissions are not set properly when you create it.  This would arise from a bad `open()` call in `generate()`:

> ```
>     int start = open(path,O_CREAT| O_TRUNC | O_WRONLY | S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);
> ```

When you include `O_CREAT` in the open flags, you are obliged to pass *an additional argument* specifying the initial mode to use in the event that a new file is created.  You are instead `OR`ing mode bits into the flags, which is incorrect.  This will resolve that particular issue, and I suspect that it will allow the two sort functions  to afterward open the file successfully:

```
    int start = open(path, O_CREAT| O_TRUNC | O_WRONLY, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);
```

Comment: I changed the flags to O_CREAT| O_TRUNC | O_RDWR but id didn't make anything happen. Now the functions open a file, however, when I have 5 lines of 5 letters, ```libSort``` makes 100 more lines with one record, ```sysSort``` doesn't produce any output

Comment: I'm sorry that your program isn't working correctly yet, @krysznys, but evidently the problem you asked about is resolved, since `libSort()` is now able to modify the file.

Comment: Thanks for help, I'll mark it as approved answer! :D